# How to pass list of arguments into a function

Tags: shell-script, function, arguments

I want to pass arguments from a loop into a function `func`. For simplicity let's say we are working with the loop

```
for x in {1..5}
do
    for y in {a..c}
    do
    echo $x$y
    done
done
```

I'm just echoing because I don't know what to do. I'd like to run the equivalent of `func 1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 3a 3b 3c 4a 4b 4c 5a 5b 5c`.

How do I do this?

Comment: In the loop: `y="$y $x"`; outside the loop: `func $y`. This only covers the most simple case. If you have special characters in your list, you need to do something more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func {1..5}` would be equivalent to `func 1 2 3 4 5`.

In general, the list of words in a *for* statement is just like any list of words in a command, so you can just replace the loop with a single invocation of the command, with whatever list you used there moved to the command arguments.

Also, you can use multiple brace expansions together: `{1..5}{a..c}` would create the list `1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 3a 3b 3c 4a 4b 4c 5a 5b 5c` (as distinct words), so in the case you show, `func {1..5}{a..c}` should work.

---

If your loop does something more complex to create the arguments to the final command, you can use an array to collect them (in Bash/ksh/zsh). Assuming we have `generate_arg` that has to be run to produce the arguments to `func`:

```
args=()
for i in {1..5}; do
    args+=( "$(generate_arg "$i")" )
done
func "${args[@]}"
```

(Using an array is better than concatenating the values to a string in that it keeps values with whitespace intact.)

Comment: There are actually two loops, they're nested. Is there a version of the first instance that works?

Comment: @CharacterClass, well, now I'm not exactly sure what your situation is then. Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/505748/edit) your post to show those nested loops in a bit more detail?

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question. The loop will serve only to concatenate the variables.

Comment: @CharacterClass, right, that looks simple since you can use multiple brace expansions. Edited, the section in the middle.